# css transition loses power when fastly pause/play it?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

why css transition loses power when I pause/play it?

What I'm doing wrong?

html:

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
<button onclick="goLeft();">goLeft</button>
<button onclick="pause();">pause</button>
<button onclick="goRight();">goRight</button>
```

css:

```
.myDiv {
   position: absolute;
   width: 60px;
   height: 90px;
   left:0px;
   top: 50px;
   background: red;
 /*transition: left 2s cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1);*/
   transition: left 2s linear;
}
```

jquery:

```
var myDiv = $('.myDiv');

function pause(){
myDiv.css({left: myDiv.css('left')});
}

function goRight(){
myDiv.css({left: 250});
}

function goLeft(){
myDiv.css({left: 0  });
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a54Ea/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
myDiv.css({left: "+=250"});
```

instead of:

```
myDiv.css({left: 250});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a54Ea/1/)**

Comment: this only works for the "right-motion", but not for the "left-motion".. what have I to change in "left: 0"??